# How to view your site with internet explorer if you have a mac?

Tags: html

Well, the title says it all. Anyone know how to do this? And no I do not want to use a VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have nothing but good things to say about [browserling](https://browserling.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Use http://browsershots.org/ - This site allows you to test your site across a lot of browsers including IE.